# Efficiency of factor vs. characters - object size

Tags: r, byte, factors

I come across something odd. I always thought storing data as factor variable if possible and if meaningful will result in a better storage efficiency.

But when I look at this:

```
object.size(c( "A", "B", "B", "0", "A", "AB", "0")) # 720 Bytes
gr <- factor(c( "A", "B", "B", "0", "A", "AB", "0"))
object.size(gr) # 336 Bytes
```

Then factor variables require more storage then characters. So was what I read about storage efficiency all wrong?

And is there an example to make the advantage of factors usage visible for beginners?

Comment: This may be useful/enlightening: https://notstatschat.tumblr.com/post/124987394001/stringsasfactors-sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, a factor is an integer vector with a `levels` attribute  (a character vector) listing the category names and a `class` attribute (another character vector) telling R that it's a factor.

A short factor tends to require *more* memory than a character vector of the same length, because the cost of storing the factor's attributes more than offsets the saving due to storing integers instead of strings. Here is an extreme example illustrating this point:

```r
x <- c("a", "b")
f <- factor(x)

class(f)
# [1] "factor"

unclass(f)
# [1] 1 2
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "a" "b"
```

Storing `f` requires storing both the integer vector `c(1L, 2L)` *and* the character vector `c("a", "b")`. In this case, the integer vector is completely redundant, because `c("a", "b")` encodes all of the information we needed in the first place.

```r
object.size(f)
# 568 bytes
object.size(x)
# 176 bytes
```

It becomes more efficient to store factors when the levels have a large number of repetitions.

```r
g <- gl(2L, 1e06L, labels = c("a", "b"))
y <- as.character(g)

object.size(g)
# 8000560 bytes
object.size(y)
# 16000160 bytes
```

Some things to keep in mind:

- Many R functions that handle categorical variables (`table`, `split`, etc.) convert character vector arguments to factors before doing anything else with them. Thus, actually doing stuff with a categorical variable almost always involves committing a factor to memory anyway.
- Factors clearly communicate to users that the variable is categorical and not merely a sequence of strings.

So, there are many good reasons to prefer factors, even if they are short.